# (Swift) Changing Image for a specific amount of time

Tags: swift

I would like to know how I can change a UIImageView for a small amount of time, say 0.1 seconds. How could I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animationImages property, it seems like GIF image

```
let images = [UIImage(named: "image1"), UIImage(named: "image2"), UIImage(named: "image3")].compactMap{$0} // ignore nil image
imageView.animationImages = images 
imageView.animationDuration = 0.1
imageView.startAnimating()
```

Or just use Timer to make an action repeat

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
   // imageView.image = ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another small question. If I have an array, say [1,2,3,4], and I want to do it so 1 changes to an image from 0-0.1 seconds, then reverts back to normal, then from 0.1-0.2 seconds, 2 changes to an image, then 0.2-0.3 seconds, 3 changes to an image, etc. What would I need to add?